# How to securely authenticate API in a .NET 8.0 Blazor client project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I am using the new Blazor template project in .NET 8.0 and want to create a component that will switch from server to WASM rendering. The component needs to call an external API that requires a token in the authorization header with every request.

My understanding is that the template's client project cannot store any sensitive information since the WASM is downloaded and the dlls could be reverse engineered to make the code visible. At the same time, the client project needs access to the token so it can make successful calls to the API.

What is the solution to this problem? I've only been able to find tutorials calling unprotected APIs. I found some Microsoft tutorials where they do call a protected API, but they conveniently use APIs, such as MicrosoftGraph, that are already deeply integrated with Azure and authenticated through user sign-in. But how do I securely call a third-party API from the client project?

Comment: @TinyWang I will get back to this question another time as I was tasked to work on something else.

Comment: that will be fine : D

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate the user in some way. All other options lead to a scenario that's almost equivalent to exposing the token in your source code and making it accessible to the client.

Create an endpoint that will issue the token only to authenticated users.

This approach ensures the token isn't embedded in the code, and you have control over its security. If you prefer not to require user authentication, you can still maintain a 'semi-secured' environment. For instance, you could restrict access from specific IP addresses. However, as I mentioned, this isn't a robust security measure.

Comment: I'm understanding your solution like this. If I add authentication to my Blazor WASM app, users will gain access to the external API token only if they successfully authenticate with the app. They will see the token, but only when authenticated with the app. Is this correct? If so, how would you handle users with different combinations of app permissions if the same token is generated for all users that gives full control of the API? Would I need to generate a token for each user that has those restrictions at the API end as well?

Comment: Also, you mentioned the token isn't embedded in the code because it's behind an API call. However, an authorized user could call that endpoint and see the token. right?

Comment: It is correct. About the permissions: It really depends on how the second API is constructed and if it allows you to generate more tokens for individual users... And yes, users will be able to see the token, but they will be able to do it anyway since you will use it to "call something"...  So even the authorized api is not really good security.

Maybe I should have mention that on the beginning: The best way would be to call the second api from your server and only serve the data to your client. This way you keep one token and it doesn't get to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You want to let different users to have different tokens which is represented that different users have different permissions to access different APIs. And you want the authentication/authorization to be secure. Am I right? And you mentioned Azure AD + GraphAPI so I want to share my ideas about how AAD and GraphAPI do for calling protected api.

When we want to call GraphAPI(equal to your custom API which is under protected), we will find that we need to give different API permissions(known as scope we need to set for generate access token) for different APIs(you can also define custom permissions). API permission is given to an Azure AD app, we need to generate access token which requiring setting scopes as the parameter when generate it to call the API. Then the API would check if the token is expired, if it contains correct scopes and some other claims value(refer to [this JWT authentication sample](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/), you could also set scope in your token claims).

The next is how you generate the access token, just like what @Alamakanambra said you need to have a login first, you can have your own logic to allow/stop users to sign in/visit specific pages depending on their user role(user role is also managed by yourself), when you know who is the current user and what role he/she has, then you should already know what API permission could be assigned to this user.

Code below is for token validation and should be placed in the API:

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(securityService.Key);
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ThisismySecretKey")),
        //IssuerSigningKey = key,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});
```

Code below is used for generating access token which should be placed in the client.

```
private string generateJwt() {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim("role","admin"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,"admin")
            //some other claims.....
        };

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
            _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
            claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
            signingCredentials: credentials);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

Token can be stored in cookie or in database, but what I shared above is that the API is protected by Bearer token. If the API is managed by yourself, you can refer to the JWT authentication to protect API, if not, then `how do I securely call a third-party API from the client project` depends on what the API requires the client do to get a valid credential so that it could visit API. A token is enough for the client to call MS graph API. Whether we cache the token in the browser or always generating a new token in your server app before calling the API, it depends on yourself. The http request containing the token we sent from the client is protected by https so that we don't need to worry if someone could intercept this https request then get the token. If your browser could be accessed by someone else or already be attacked, then this is another story. By the way, token has a expiring time, if we set it with a very short period(e.g. 10s), then we don't need to store it.

Comment: [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-wasm/blob/main/WebApp-graph-user/Call-MSGraph/README.md) for blazor call ms graph api which requiring an access token

Comment: [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-protected-web-api-overview) for using Azure AD to protect web api.